# How to specify gridspec location by numbers?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, matplotlib-gridspec

I read the instruction in [Customizing Location of Subplot Using GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) and try out the following codes and got the plot layout:

```
 import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec  
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, :])
    ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, :-1])
    ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1:, -1])
    ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[-1, 0])
    ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[-1, -2])
```

[image]

I understand that `gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)` will give a 3*3 layout, but what it means for `gs[0, :]` `gs[1, :-1]` `gs[1:, -1]` `gs[-1, 0]` `gs[-1, -2]`? I look up online but not found a detailed expanation, and I also try to change the index but not found a regular pattern. Could anyone give me some explanation or throw me a link about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)`, you have created essentially a 3 by 3 "grid" for your plots. From there, you can use `gs[...,...]` to specify the location and size of each subplot, by the number of rows and columns each subplot fills in that 3x3 grid. Looking in more detail:

`gs[1, :-1]` specifies *where* on the gridspace your subplot will be. For instance `ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, :-1])` says: put the axis called `ax2` on the **first row** (denoted by `[1,...`) (remember that in python, there is zero indexing, so this essentially means "second row down from the top"), stretching **from the 0th column *up until* the last column** (denoted by `...,:-1]`). Because our gridspace is 3 columns wide, this means it will stretch 2 columns.

Perhaps it's better to show this by annotating each axis in your example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec  
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, :-1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1:, -1])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[-1, 0])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[-1, -2])

ax1.annotate('ax1, gs[0,:] \ni.e. row 0, all columns',xy=(0.5,0.5),color='blue', ha='center')
ax2.annotate('ax2, gs[1, :-1]\ni.e. row 1, all columns except last', xy=(0.5,0.5),color='red', ha='center')
ax3.annotate('ax3, gs[1:, -1]\ni.e. row 1 until last row,\n last column', xy=(0.5,0.5),color='green', ha='center')
ax4.annotate('ax4, gs[-1, 0]\ni.e. last row, \n0th column', xy=(0.5,0.5),color='purple', ha='center')
ax5.annotate('ax5, gs[-1, -2]\ni.e. last row, \n2nd to last column', xy=(0.5,0.5), ha='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- In a case where multiple rows of a varying number of evenly spaced subplots are required, or the opposite, the number of columns (or rows) may need to be a multiple of the number of subplots.
- For example, given 3 rows of 2, 3, and 4 evenly spaced subplots, use `ncols=12`, because 12 is the lowest common multiple for 2, 3, and 4.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8), tight_layout=True)
gs = GridSpec(nrows=3, ncols=12)

ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0, :6])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 6:])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1, :4])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 4:8])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 8:])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[2, :3])
ax6 = plt.subplot(gs[2, 3:6])
ax7 = plt.subplot(gs[2, 6:9])
ax8 = plt.subplot(gs[2, 9:])
```

[image]