# Create single parent figure where the Y-axis represents depth

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, axis

Using the dataset below, it represent amplitudes recorded a varying depths across time.

```
data = {
    'Time': [0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10],
    'Depth_63.5': [161, 143, 134, 147, 163],
    'Depth_64.5': [183, 190, 375, 255, 241],
    'Depth_65.5': [711, 727, 914, 756, 747],
}
```

I can plot the graph for time vs amplitudes as seen below.

[image]

However, what I wanted is the graph I have be plotted on a parent figure with Time on X-axis and Depth on Y-axis as seen below.
[image]

How do I achieve this result? My current code is seen below...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Sample data..
data = {
    'Time': [0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10],
    'Depth_63.5': [161, 143, 134, 147, 163],
    'Depth_64.5': [183, 190, 375, 255, 241],
    'Depth_65.5': [711, 727, 914, 756, 747],
}

# Convert data to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Extract depth levels from column names
depth_levels = [col.split('_')[1] for col in df.columns if 'Depth_' in col]

# Create the parent figure with subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

# Loop through each depth level and plot Time vs Amplitude on the same axes
for depth_level in depth_levels:
    ax.plot(df['Time'], df[f'Depth_{depth_level}'], label=f'Depth {depth_level}')

# Customize the plot appearance
ax.set_title('Depth vs Time vs Amplitude')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (us)')
ax.set_ylabel('Depth Levels')
ax.legend()
ax.grid(True)

# Show the parent figure
plt.show()
```

I think the solution would be something close to multiple Y-Axes, but the secondary Y-axis will rely on primary Y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this using matplotlib 'GridSpec' module, so make sure it is imported like so: `import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec`

[GridSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323348/how-to-specify-gridspec-location-by-numbers) additional control over the placements of subplots, also the margins and the spacings between the individual subplots. It also allows us to create axes which can spread over multiple grid areas.

I created a GridSpec with number of rows equal to the length of my dataframe and number of columns equal to 1. On which I plotted the Depth Vs Time while setting the line style to none to prevent it from showing on the figure (it is the axis of this plot I wanted not the plot itself). Then I added a `add_subplot` to the gridspec and plot then plot the respective depth levels from the dataframe as in the question above.

The final code is as follow:-

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec


# Sample data..
data = {
    'Time': [0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10],
    'Depth_63.5': [161, 143, 134, 147, 163],
    'Depth_64.5': [183, 190, 375, 255, 241],
    'Depth_65.5': [711, 727, 914, 756, 747],
}

# Convert data to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Extract depth levels from column names
depth_levels = [col.split('_')[1] for col in df.columns if 'Depth_' in col]


# Create the parent figure with subplots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

# Create a grid of subplots using gridspec
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=len(depth_levels), ncols=1)

# Create an axis for the common main axis
main_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 0])
main_ax.plot(df['Time'].tolist()[:len(depth_levels)], depth_levels, linestyle='None')
main_ax.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=15)
main_ax.set_ylabel('Depth', fontsize=15)
main_ax.axis('on')
# main_ax.grid(True)

# Loop through each depth level and plot Time vs Amplitude on the same axes
for i, depth_level in enumerate(depth_levels):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i, 0])
    ax.plot(df['Time'], df[f'Depth_{depth_level}'], label=f'Depth {depth_level}')
    ax.axis('off')
    # ax.tick_params(axis='both', direction='in', length=6, color='r', labelleft=False, labelbottom=False)

    
# Adjust spacing between subplots
# plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig(f'001.png', dpi=300)
# Show the parent figure
plt.show()
```

[image]

You may customize the axes and grid to what you wanted.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for [*Subplots*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#subplots) :

```
(
    df.set_index("Time").iloc[:, ::-1]
        .plot(subplots=True, figsize=(8, 6), # with optional legend=False
              xlabel="Time", title="Depth vs Time vs Amplitude")
)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, top=0.94, left=0.1)
plt.gcf().supylabel("Depth")
plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. However, I did like the Y-axis to be depth levels and each of the subplots will start at its corresponding depth level (a kind of multiple Y-Axes).